# Finding management IP on network

Tags: switch, ipv4

I am trying to locate the IP address of a managed hirschmann switch in a small network set up in a spare room for the sake of learning about them as they are used at work. The switch in question [1of7] is acting like an unmanaged switch with no trace of any IP address - How do I find its IP address?

To eliminate the other switches that I have addresses into a new range of IPs, I linked the switch between a laptop and the gateway router, traffic passes through [I'm writing this question through the damm thing] 
I ran tracert and only the gateway router comes up. It passes through traffic on all ports but no register of it on wireshark that I can see. 
As well as wireshark, I tried angry IP, advanced IP, HIdiscovery, industrial HI Vision and found the addresses of 6 out of the 7 switches but can not get anything out of the 7th switch.

The switches were all Ebay purchases some new some 2nd hand unfortunately the seller didn't reset to factory settings with this one.

All the switches have a RJ11 v.24 serial port for management, I have spent the last few days making up serial cables trying different pin outs as the Hirschmann cable is 6 weeks away from Germany. I believe it is the same as the Schneider cable which has a description of pin out there website. I am also using a USB to serial converter which opens up com port 6. On one of the known switchs that I log in through webinterface it has all the telnet/ssh/bootP/v24 enabled but I can not open a telnet session with the switch. Mainly because I have little idea what I am doing, so if the answer to the question is use a serial cable, please be specific!

Comment: Ask the person who set it up, or look at the configuration from the console.

Comment: Ricky - As per the question, the switches were bought off ebay some 2nd hand some new, if I could get in touch with who ever set them up I wouldn't be asking here, as per the bottom of the question I have been struggling to get into it via the serial port / console....

Comment: What model of switch is it just out of curiosity? I was just poking around looking at those after seeing this. There has to be a viable solution of some sort....Although it was made in Germany...and we know how they like to make it easy to work on the things they manufacture =).

Comment: If you can physically touch a switch, then you own it.  The company should have instructions on their website (or via customer service) on how to log into a switch if you lose the password.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

**LLDP** is the tool for discovering/visibility into switches on your LAN(s).  BTW, if you don't have access to any of them via console, issue LLDP commands from your router, try and web into your default gateway, or load an LLDP client on your laptop.  Something like https://www.hanewin.net/lldp-e.htm

#### [Hirschmann Reference Manual](https://e-catalog.hirschmann.com/download/managed/pim/c976d9c2-5371-46ce-8773-aa043f046d6a/RM_CLI_L2B_40_en.pdf;jsessionid=6C6ED1A05904D9EB3403304E98C812C2?type=attachment)

`show lldp remote-data <{slot/port|all}> mgmt-addr`
Display the remote data's management address only.

> 4.8.13 lldp Enable/disable the LLDP/IEEE802.1AB functionality on this device. If disabled, the LLDP protocol will become inactive, but the
> LLDP MIBs can still be accessed. This command is a shorthand notation
> for lldp config chas sis admin-state {off|on} (see “lldp config
> chassis admin-state” on page 153).
> **The default setting is on.**

Answer (score 0):

Most managed switches can have a management interface on any VLAN, which may or may not be a VLAN used on any of the ports. if you are using VLAN 10 with the `192.168.1.0/24` subnet for the access ports, the switch management interface could be on the same, or a different, VLAN with a completely different address, such as `10.1.2.3` with a gateway of `10.1.2.1`, or it may not even have a configured management interface.

Using `tracert` doesn't do any good unless the switch is a layer-3 switch and it is the gateway of the subnet you are on since it only counts router hops.

There is not really any "magic" method to discover this unless you have console access, and you would still need to know the management password. Your best bet is to contact the manufacturer about your problem.

Comment: Factory reset via Telnet / CLI it is

Comment: If you have access via telnet or (console) CLI, then you already know the management IP.

Comment: I physcially have access to the switch and serial port but as of yet have not managed to get in. I have had issue making up a cable, following the instruction from a reseller [Schneider]. The cable hirschmann sell is a 6 week lead time from germany and there is no rj12- db9[rs232] standard, it appears to be a proprietary cable to Hirschmann - I have ordered it and also some from Hong Kong [Schneider].

Comment: Ron speaks true. Finding the management IP of any device is different for everything. You can either connect via console, or if the switch does not have a console cable, then you must improvise. I would sourest to connect directly on the switch and then use the IP Scanner http://www.advanced-ip-scanner.com/ to scan the subnet to which you are given the IP Address to search fore some clues.